# Publish specific folder with assetic

Tags: symfony, assetic

I have a directory structure looking like this, using bower for frontend stuff:

```
app/Resources/public
    bower_components
         jquery
         lightbox
         ...
    css
         base.css

app/Resources/views
    layouts
         admin
              base.html.twig
         site
              base.html.twig
```

Later on I use ascetic to publish all the files, however the files that GETS published is only those who are referenced in a file, for example like this:

```
...

{% stylesheets
'../app/Resources/public/bower_components/normalize-css/normalize.css'
'../app/Resources/public/css/base.css'
'../app/Resources/public/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
'../app/Resources/public/bower_components/lightbox/css/lightbox.css' filter='cssrewrite,?uglifycss' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}

...
```

Which is all files, no problem, except that the lightbox.css tries to reach images that lies within `app/Resources/public/bower_components/lightbox/img` and later gets boiled down to `http://something.com/app/Resources/public/bower_components/lightbox/img/close.png` which is not accessible and should be referencing the web directory, I know this is solvable by having the bower components within a bundle, or move shit to one place or another, I'm just asking if there is a proper Symfony2/assetic way to solve this, like publishing that particular img folder and referencing it that way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `cssrewrite` filter to rewrite your `css` and fix the images issue, check this :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#cookbook-assetic-cssrewrite

Comment: Using the cssrewrite filter makes the url's absolute, nothing else, app/Resources/* is not accessible from outside and should not be, the question is more about moving a specific folder, just like ascetic does when it publishes referenced files, else there will be no way to access them.